# Tracking when users click on a download link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a application that allows user to download the latest builds of an application. I need to record whenever a user clicks on a link. I have create a UserVersions model that tracks this data. But I'm not sure how to make the call, via javascript or some rails utility to create a new record. I have an idea of how to do it using jquery. But I'm not sure how to get the version_id for each link.

config/routes.rb

```
post 'user_versions/create/:user_id/:version_id', to: 'user_versions/#create'
```

app/controllers/user_versions_controller.rb

```
class UserVersionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = params[:user_id]
    version = params[:version_id]
    UserVersion.find_or_create_by(user: user, version: version)
  end

end
```

app/view/version/_full.html.erb

```
...

      <li class="download cols-lg-4 pull-right">
        <% if (version.app[:app_type] == 'ios') %>
          <%= button_to 'Download', "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=#{CGI::escape version.plist_url}", class:"btn-primary btn-small pull-right" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= button_to 'Download', version.plist_url, class: 'download-btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right', method: :get %>
        <% end %>
      </li>

...
```

app.js.erb

```
...
$('.download-btn').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/user_versions/create/" + current_user[:id] +"/" + :version_id"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the link go to a URL controlled by your rails app. Then when the request arrives at your controller you can record the hit then redirect to the actual download URL.

Comment: I do not want the user to have to leave the current view